# Laravel - Failed to load resource error 500

Tags: laravel

I've a problem with my website, the layout load properly (and CSS) but no JS and page in yield.
I've copy paste the layout of my other website, inclued tje JS and CSS file, I do not understand why it does not work while on other sites it's good..

Code for include the JS and CSS file: `<script src="{{url('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>`

As you can see, the page is empty, and this is not normal.

Image of error:
[image]

Comment: try checking in View Page Source to if your JS are loaded correctly, if you cant see them then check your template that loads in your View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh... ok.
I've forget to DL From:: into my project. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was creating a recent Laravel project however mine was narrowed down too 2 problems. 1 being the JS had an error and 2nd was the way I called it.

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/jquery.min.js') !!}"></script>
```